# PHP Js Only first row of the table can be use(button)

Tags: javascript, php, html

Im new at this and still confuse about my problem, so here is a table for my php

```
<table>
            <tr>
                <th align="center">ID</th>
                <th align="center">Project Name</th>
                <th align="center">Due Date</th>
                <th align="center">Sub Date</th>
                <th align="center">Comment</th>
                <th align="center">Status</th>
                <th align="center">Option</th>
            </tr>

            <tr>
            
            <?php
                
                while ($res2=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2)) {

                    echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<td>".$res2['project_id']."</td>";
                    echo "<td>".$res2['project_name']."</td>";
                    echo "<td>".$res2['duedate']."</td>";
                    echo "<td>".$res2['subdate']."</td>";
                    echo "<td>\"".$res2['comment']."\"</td>";
                    echo "<td>".$res2['status']."</td>";
                    
                    //as you can see, id = myId
                    echo "<td><a href=\"#\" id=\"myId\" class=\"button\">View</a>";
                }?>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

supposedly when button next to each row is clicked, a popup window will appear but only the first row works, and the other buttons do nothing. I did search for this problem like 2 hours already, most of them talk about unique id, but how can I implement or fix for this problem.

Here is a script for this

```
        document.getElementById('myId').addEventListener("click", function () {
            document.querySelector('.bg-modal').style.display = "flex";
        });
```

I would really appreciate for your help, thanks a lot.

Comment: An `id` is supposed to be Unique, yours are not so the js only sees the first one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try:

```
[].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('[id^="myId"]'))
.map(el => el.addEventListener("click", function () {
    document.querySelector('.bg-modal').style.display = "flex";
}));
```

and you should change your code:

```
 $i = 0;
 while ($res2=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2)) {
     ......
     //as you can see, 
     echo "<td><a href=\"#\" class=\"class-{++$i}\" class=\"button\">View</a>";
 }
```

now, js code:

```
[].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('[class^="class-"]'))
.map(el => el.addEventListener("click", function () {
    document.querySelector('.bg-modal').style.display = "flex";
}));
```

Comment: Thank you, this one working great, I have another question if you mind to answer..my problem now is I want to pass value id(in while loop) to be use and call outside of that loop, for example "project_id" is what I selected on the table, and I want to call all the data within the database base on the id which is project_id..but whenever i clicked any of the row in table, always the last one being called because I know that while loop process and ended up on the last row so the id also assigned as the last value..is there any way I can overcome this problem? (*Im sorry for bad english)

Comment: you can try:
echo "<td><a data-projid="{$projectid}" href=\"#\" class=\"class-{++$i}\" class=\"button\">View</a>";
in js code can use: el.dataset['projid'] =>>> project id

Comment: im sorry but how im supposed to put el.dataset['projid'] =>>> project id ?

Comment: it's here:
`.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('[class^="class-"]'))
.map(el => {
    console.log(el.dataset['projid']);
    el.addEventListener("click", function () {
        document.querySelector('.bg-modal').style.display = "flex";
    }
}));`

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you should just use **unique ID** for every HTML elements, if you intend to create multiple elements with same behavior, use `class` instead.

After you change it to `class`, you can select all the elements work by assigning once by using `querySelectorAll()`.

Here is the working example:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('button.click').forEach(elem => 
{
  elem.addEventListener('click', () => {
    document.querySelector('div').style.background = elem.innerText;
  });
});
```

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<button id="1" class="click">green</button>
<button id="2" class="click">blue</button>
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Ids should be unique.**
You should not use twice the same id in a page.
**Classes** serves that purpose.

So first, we should add a class on every buttons that tells us that this button is used to show the modal. And we also remove the id, as it would not be unique and is also useless here.

```
echo "<td><a href=\"#\" class=\"modal-button button\">View</a>";
```

Then, to add the listener, we want to target every buttons that has this new “modal-button” we just added. The right way to do so, would be to target elements with the class, iterate over them and add the listener.

```
document.getElementsByClassName(‘modal-button’).forEach(button => {

    button.addEventListener("click", function () {
        document.querySelector('.bg-modal').style.display = "flex";
    });

})
```

Hopefully this helps!